# Send ajax post request to servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, tomcat7

I can not send a simple request to the servlet to jQuery tools. But at the same time if I go through the form, then everything works on hurray. Here is the index.html from which I want to send the user's login. Login.js, in which I form the request itself, SerletStore.java itself servlet. And the structure of the whole project.

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#login-submit").click(function(){
        var data = {
            username: $("#user").prop("value")
        }

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/ChallengeClient/store",
            data: {
                username: $("#user").prop("value")
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        }).done(function() {
            alert('Success');
        });
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form name="form-login">
            <span class="fontawesome-user"></span>
            <input type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя">
            <span class="fontawesome-lock"></span>
            <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Пароль">
            <input type="submit" id="login-submit" value="Вход">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ServletStore.java**

```
package servlet;

import server.service.HelloWebService;
import server.service.HelloWebServiceImplService;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name="store", urlPatterns = "/store")
public class ServletStore extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // подключаемся к тегу service в wsdl описании
        HelloWebServiceImplService helloService = new HelloWebServiceImplService();
        // получив информацию из тега service подключаемся к самому веб-сервису
        HelloWebService hello = helloService.getHelloWebServiceImplPort();

        // обращаемся к веб-сервису и выводим результат в консоль
        /*String error = hello.getHelloString("!! Challenge !!");*/

        String error = "";
        String username = (String) req.getParameter("username");
        if (username.equals("")) {
            error = "Не было введено имя пользователя";
        }
        req.setAttribute("error", "Не было введено имя пользователя");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/loginError.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: For starters you aren't preventing default form submit. Beyond that you haven't told us anything of value regarding troubleshooting

Comment: @charlietfl, 
What else do you need to know for debugging? Say please. And how can I prevent the submission of a form?

Comment: Try [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: @charlietfl
$("#form").preventDefault(); - added in .click. Did not help ;(

Comment: So what's happening? (And what's supposed to happen? That's not even clear.)